# Is a MPI_Wait necessary after a MPI_Isend?

Tags: c, mpi

For example,

```
if (rank == 0) {
    MPI_Isend(&sendbuf, ..., 1, ..., &request);
    MPI_Wait(&request, ...);  /* Is this wait necessary? */
} else if (rank == 1) {
    MPI_Irecv(&recvbuf, ..., 0, ..., &request);
    MPI_Wait(&request, ...);
}
```

Is the MPI_Wait following MPI_Isend necessary? In theory,

> A separate send complete call is needed to complete the communication.

But in practice, it works without explicitly waiting for MPI_Isend.

Answer (score 5):

A separate complete (e.g. `MPI_Wait` ) call is necessary.

For `MPI_Isend`, the completion ensures, that the message was copied out of the send buffer. Before message completion you must not modify or deallocate the send buffer.

Similarly, for `MPI_Irecv`, you must complete the call to ensure that the message has been received in the receive buffer. Before message completion you must not try to read the message from the receive buffer. Evidently this implies that you must not write or deallocate the receive buffer.

Message completion is done either by `MPI_Wait`, a successfull `MPI_Test` or their mutiple completion (all/any/some) variants.

In addition to completing the communication, these function also dealloate the communication request object. Technically you can do this without completing the communication using `MPI_Request_free`.

There is no way to give a recommendation on what to do based on your limited code example. Without more code, it is impossible to tell you where to correctly place the `MPI_Wait`. If you place it right there, the code is correct, but you might as well just use `MPI_Send` / `MPI_Recv`.

Ommiting the message completion will lead to resource leaks and most likely incorrect code.

MPI is hard, nonblocking MPI is even harder. If you are beginner, try to stick with the blocking MPI calls. Nonblocking calls seem to be overused by beginners and lead to code that is very difficult to reason about. Also never trust a code to be correct just because it works for you.

Comment: Can I replace the MPI_Wait following MPI_Isend by a MPI_Request_free, like [Example 3.12](http://mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report.pdf#87)? How can this guarantee the completion of the sendings?

Comment: If you use `MPI_Request_free`, you cannot guarantee the complition of the send. Don't use it unless you really know what you are doing.